# RemoveDuplicates Method doesn't work well, it remains two or more of duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub no_DuplicatesNsort()
    Sheets(1).Columns(1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    Sheets(1).Columns(1).Sort Key1:=Cells(1, 1), Order1:=xlAscending
End Sub
```

Is there any problem in this code? The data that I want to remove duplicates is located sheets(1).Columns(1), and every time I do run the code, then it keeps remaining at least 2 duplicates for every value.

I want to have a clear data without any duplicates. What am I missing for the code?

Comment: Do you still get the issue if you use the range object? `Sheets(1).Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes`

Comment: What kind of data are you working with? If it's strings, could there be extra spaces on some lines?

Comment: What happens when you run it a second time? does it clear the remaining duplicates?

Comment: Oh yeah I'm using string-type data, as I checked now, the problem was the extra spaces Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

### `Application.Trim`, `Sort`, and `RemoveDuplicates`

... applied on a single-column range

```vb
Sub Test()
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns(1)
    
    With rg ' use a range variable to get the IntelliSense working
        .Value = Application.Trim(.Value)
        .Sort rg, xlAscending, , , , , , xlYes
        .RemoveDuplicates 1, xlYes ' works faster on a sorted range
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Cool, I wasn't aware `RemoveDuplicates` worked faster with a sorted set. Does the extra speed make up for the extra time sorting?

Comment: idk... I'm testing it and i think the extra time sorting actually roughly doubles total script time.